# 3-way Fixture Wiring Question

Tags: light-fixture, multiway-switch

A handyman replaced a light fixture for my sister, but badly screwed up the wiring such that it no longer turns off by either switch (everything worked fine with the old fixture).  I just got here and opened it up, and saw he had the fixtures ground connected to the Red wire, so I can't trust anything in the fixture's current wiring.

I have

- 2x switches

  - One of the switches that I peeked at has 2 relevant wires going into the box, of which the switch is connected with 1-black and 2-reds -- I didn't dig deeply into how it's wired, but this seems to imply this circuit isn't connected in any way I'd expect.
- In the fixture box (the only part that's been messed with) there are 3 wires into the box:

  - 1x 3-wire+ground cable into fixture (with red/white/black)
  - 2x 2-wire+ground cable into fixture (with black/white)
  - All ground wires into the box are connected.

The fixture box was incorrectly connected such that all whites were tied together (including the fixture), all blacks tied together (including the fixture), and the red wire connected to the fixture's ground wire. I have no idea what the wiring looked at before the handyman "fixed" it.

The fixture originally worked as expected with either of the two switches.  After the handyman left the light is always on and both switches are non-functional.

What would the correct wiring for the fixture be here to restore normal function to the switches?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a picture

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just edited the question to hopefully be a bit clearer.  A photo isn't going to be very helpful here.  As noted, the handyman screwed up the wiring to "fix" things, instead of simply connecting the new fixture with the same wiring scheme as the old as I'd have expected (I didn't find out until weeks later).

Comment: If you haven’t already, take that red wire off the ground. As noted, a multimeter or (sometimes, not always) a pen tester can identify the hot wires at the fixture. My gut is that the two wire is permanently hot and that the three wire acts as a switch loop, but you’ll never know without diagnostics.

Comment: Yes, fixing the ground was the very first thing I did, thxs. I think I'll have to bite the bullet and hire an electrician (and try to send that handyman the bill after) - no time to buy the appropriate tools and fix it be4 I head home

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the wires on those switches, especially the ones that connect to each other (the travelers). I use a multimeter with looooong cables and do continuity testing. Also, a pen tester is pretty handy to test hot wires.[image: Pen tester]